Is there a name for the set of lines with slopes $1$, $2$, $3$, $\ldots$?
I've recently stumbled across a pattern involving these infinite sets of lines that meet at a single point and have slopes 1, 2, 3, 4...

Is there a name for these lines and have they been studied anywhere?
Thanks!
(The context of the problem isn't relevant to this question. I'm happy to explain it but I don't want to confuse the post.)

I think basically you're discovering that a vertical line (i.e., the line $x = 0$) is a line with "infinite" slope. Notice that you'd converge to the same line if you took the sequence of lines with slopes $-1,-2,\dots$ so really $x=0$ has undefined slope since you can take it to be $\pm\infty$.

Looks a bit like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_broom
